# how to find out which us states have bigger population in 2019

Tags: sql, r

I'm very new to R. I would like to analyze the demographic pattern of Us States.

My dataset looks like these

| US State | 2020 | 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hawaii | 1,451,911 | 1,415,872 |
| California | 39,368,078 | 39,512,223 |
| New Jersey | 9,365,801 | 9,365,801 |
| Rhode Island | 1,097,379 | 1,087,379 |
| Texas | 29,145,505 | 28,986,794 |
| Arkansas | 3,216,598 | 3,512,223 |

My goal is to find out in which US States the population has decreased. Since I am very new I don't know how to code to find out the solution. How can I found out this problem?

Comment: do you need sql code or R-implementation ?

Comment: R implementation but my prof say it should be a combinnation of sql and R for finding the solution

Comment: Then please specify also database you use

Comment: I don't use database. I only have acsv file and want to find out which us states have a downward trend in population

Comment: Welcome to SO, JonathanHemingway! It is possible to use R and SQL without a "proper" database by using `sqldf` (operates on in-R objects), or `RSQLite` or `duckdb` for file-based databases. If you don't know what all of that means (which is fine), and your prof has not given you the information on how to construct and use SQL queries, then I suggest you stick with R and not add the [tag:sql] tag. A "database" is different from a table of information as you have above, and tagging a question with "sql" changes the mindset of potential answers outside of what you can use. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R, you can use several ways to achieve this.

First, create the data (next time it would be nicer if you gave your data as code, by pasting in the output of `dput(data)` or by giving some ready to use dummy-data):

```
data <- data.frame(
  "US State" = c("Hawaii", "California", "New Jersey", "Rhode Island", "Texas", "Arkansas"),
  "y2020" = c(1451911, 39368078, 9365801, 1097379, 29145505, 3216598),
  "y2019" = c(1415872, 39512223, 9365801, 1087379, 28986794, 3512223))
```

You can use a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
new <- data %>%
  filter(y2019 > y2020)
```

Or the base R approach:

```
new <- data[data$y2019 > data$y2020,]
```

Or you could add an additional column indicating whether the condition is `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
data$rising <- data$y2019 > data$y2020
```

Comment: In base R you can also do `subset(data, y2019 > y2020)`.